# How to make custom ggplot map plot for anatomical locations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a custom plot, rather like a chloropleth map plot (https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/). However, I want to create a custom map which is based on a generalised anatomical representation of a bone. The data I have represents area of a bone involved in loosening as defined in the image below (adapted from Wikipedia)

my example data looks like this:

```
#example of fake data
df <- data.frame(caseid = 1:100,
           zone1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone3 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone5 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone6 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
           zone7 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100))
```

I want to construct a 'map' of these bone areas adjacent to the implant and change the colour of each zone according tot he count of the instances of loosening in this zone. See example below:

[image]

I have searched for ways to do this but I cannot seem to find an existing example or an existing map to use in the normal way (see chloropleth map plot example link).

I have read about making spatial objects and importing these to plot onto but I am not sure where to start.

Question: 
1) What are the steps involved in making a custom plotting 'map'?

2) is it possible to make spatial objects from images (i.e. is there a quick method?)?

Comment: This should be possible with `geom_tile()` to make colored zones, and `cowplot::draw_image()` to add a picture of the bone. It won't be a quick method though, this will take some manual adjustment to get the `geom_tile()' plot to match up with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your example image as background for a plot and created boundaries for each zone in a 1 to 10 scale. I end up with a new dataframe, that illustrate how you can store your data.

**packages**

```
pkg <- c("ggplot2", "ggpubr", "png")
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  segment = c("segment 1", "segment 2", "segment 3", "segment 4",
              "segment 5", "segment 6", "segment 7"),
  xmin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5),
  xmax = c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 10, 10, 10, 10),
  ymin = c(7.5, 4.2, 1, 0, 1, 4.2, 7.5),
  ymax = c(10, 7.5, 4.2, 1, 4.2, 7.5, 10),
  instances_loosening = rnorm(7, 100, sd = 40)
  )
```

**Import imagen**

```
img <- png::readPNG("bone.png")
```

**Plot**
To create the segments use `geom_rect` function from ggplot. Map each x and y min and max, and fill by instances each segment.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df) +
  ggpubr::background_image(img) +
  ggplot2::geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = xmin,
        ymin = ymin,
        xmax = xmax,
        ymax = ymax,
        fill = instances_loosening),
    color  = "black", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. What a clear and helpful answer. I will have a go!

Comment: Out of interest do you know if there is a way to make each box a bar (ike a bar chart) which grows with count of cases or similar?

Comment: It can be done. Just try this. `ggplot(df) + geom_col(aes(x = segment, y = instances_loosening)`

Comment: Thanks Johan, I imagine this will make a bar chart in standard format. I did not make my question clear, What I mean is to make bars in the space of the geom_rect which exist in your original answer so that the geom_rect expand to represent the count value in a bar chart fashion (grow in length away from midline)

Comment: I do not know if that can be done. Anyway, a good visualization would be to make a grid with two plots: the one of the question and a barchar in standar format. This function can help with that `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`. You can try to make a bar char with the bone as background, an the tiles just to delimint the areas (without fill).